# Fedora 20 system freezes when the Fedora logo appears

Tags: fedora, login

The system is feodra20-64bit. After I tried to install a rpm of adobe reader, I am not able to log in. It feezes at that "f" logo.

However I can use command line to log in.

The below is `vi /var/log/messages` and `vi /var/log/secure`
[image: messeage] and [image]

Comment: adobe reader is probably a coincidence. Have you tried to boot with SELinux disabled? `gdm` isn't able to communicate with dbus for some reason.

Comment: You says two things or only one thing? Disabling selinux may correlate with gdm,right?

Comment: I followed the link here http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-adobe-acrobat-pdf-reader-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/, but I just run `yum localinstall AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i486linux_enu.rpm`